# BigQuery fails on parsing dates in M/D/YYYY format from CSV file

Tags: google-bigquery

#### Problem

I'm attempting to create a BigQuery table from a CSV file in Google Cloud Storage.

I'm explicitly defining the schema for the load job (below) and set *header rows to skip* = 1.

#### Data

```
$ cat date_formatting_test.csv
id,shipped,name
0,1/10/2019,ryan
1,2/1/2019,blah
2,10/1/2013,asdf
```

#### Schema

```
id:INTEGER,
shipped:DATE,
name:STRING
```

#### Error

BigQuery produces the following error:

> Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse '1/10/2019' as date for field shipped (position 1) starting at location 17

#### Questions

I understand that this date isn't in ISO format (2019-01-10), which I'm assuming will work.

However, I'm trying to define a more flexible input configuration whereby BigQuery will correctly load any date that the average American would consider valid.

1. Is there a way to specify the expected date format(s)?
2. Is there a separate configuration / setting to allow me to successfully load the provided CSV in with the schema defined as-is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [listed limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#limitations):

```
When you load CSV or JSON data, values in DATE columns must use 
the dash (-) separator and the date must be in the following 
format: YYYY-MM-DD (year-month-day).
```

So this leaves us with 2 options:

## Option 1: ETL

- Place new CSV files in Google Cloud Storage
- That in turn triggers a [Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/) or [Google Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/) job to:

  - Edit the date column in all the CSV files
  - Save the edited files back to Google Cloud Storage
  - Load the modified CSV files into Google BigQuery

## Option 2: ELT

- Load the CSV file as-is to BigQuery (i.e. your schema should be modified to `shipped:STRING`)
- Create a BigQuery view that transforms the `shipped` field from a string to a recognised date format. Use `SELECT id, PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', shipped) AS shipped, name`
- Use that view for your analysis

I'm not sure, from your description, if this is a once-off job or recurring. If it's once-off, I'd go with Option 2 as it requires the least effort. Option 1 requires a bit more effort, and would only be worth it for recurring jobs.

Comment: Funny thing, the format `DD-MM-YYYY` does not work from command line with `bq load`, but from the BQ GUI works perfectly: I've just uploaded a few CSVs with dates like `21-11-2020` without any issue.

Comment: Attention, a gotcha is if you leave a first row with column names... you'll get a DATE PARSE error (if you define a DATE data type).