# googleapis / python-bigquery: Client.load_dataframe_to_table fails with PyArrow "TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)"

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

Given the following code:

```py
try:
    dest_table = bigquery.table.Table(table_id, schema)
    job = self.client.load_table_from_dataframe(
        df_data, # pd.DataFrame
        dest_table,
        job_config=bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig(schema=schema)
    )
    job.result()
except TypeError:
    with pd.option_context("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None, "display.width", None):
        LOG.error("Failed to upload dataframe: \n\n%s\n", df_data.to_csv(header=True, index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC))
        LOG.error("\n%s\n", df_data.dtypes)
        if schema:
            LOG.error(
                "schema: \n\n%s", 
                ('[\n  ' + ',\n  '.join(json.dumps(field) for field in schema) + '\n]\n')
            )
        LOG.error(f"dest_table_id: {dest_table_id}")
    raise
```

BigQuery's `Client.load_table_from_dataframe` raises from pyarrow with:

```
dags/utils/database/_bigquery.py:257: in load_file_to_table
    job = self.client.load_table_from_dataframe(
lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py:2233: in load_table_from_dataframe
    _pandas_helpers.dataframe_to_parquet(
lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py:486: in dataframe_to_parquet
    arrow_table = dataframe_to_arrow(dataframe, bq_schema)
lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py:450: in dataframe_to_arrow
    bq_to_arrow_array(get_column_or_index(dataframe, bq_field.name), bq_field)
lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py:224: in bq_to_arrow_array
    return pyarrow.Array.from_pandas(series, type=arrow_type)
pyarrow/array.pxi:859: in pyarrow.lib.Array.from_pandas
    ???
pyarrow/array.pxi:265: in pyarrow.lib.array
    ???
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

>   ???
E   TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Yet, when investigating with the ERROR debug prints, it seems like the provided DataFrame matches the expected schema of every field provided for the table:

```
ERROR    utils.database._bigquery:_bigquery.py:265 Failed to upload dataframe:

"clinic_key","schedule_template_time_interval_key","schedule_template_key","date_key","schedule_owner_key","schedule_template_schedule_track_key","schedule_content_label_key","start_time_key","end_time_key","priority"
"clitest11111111111111111111111","1","1","2021-01-01","1","1","1","19:00:00","21:00:00",1
"clitest11111111111111111111111","1","1","2021-01-01","1","1","2","20:00:00","20:30:00",2
"clitest11111111111111111111111","1","1","2021-01-01","1","1","3","20:20:00","20:30:00",3

ERROR    utils.database._bigquery:_bigquery.py:266
clinic_key                              object
schedule_template_time_interval_key     object
schedule_template_key                   object
date_key                                object
schedule_owner_key                      object
schedule_template_schedule_track_key    object
schedule_content_label_key              object
start_time_key                          object
end_time_key                            object
priority                                 int64
dtype: object

ERROR    utils.database._bigquery:_bigquery.py:268 schema:

[
  {"name": "clinic_key", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
  {"name": "schedule_template_time_interval_key", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
  {"name": "schedule_template_key", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
  {"name": "date_key", "type": "DATE", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
  {"name": "schedule_owner_key", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
  {"name": "schedule_template_schedule_track_key", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
  {"name": "schedule_content_label_key", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
  {"name": "start_time_key", "type": "TIME", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
  {"name": "end_time_key", "type": "TIME", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
  {"name": "priority", "type": "INT64", "mode": "NULLABLE"}
]
```

I tried converting the (start_time_key, end_time_key) fields to INT (number of seconds since start of day) before calling load_table_from_dataframe, but it did not solve the issue. Besides that I am a stumped; I don't understand which field is supposed to be an integer but is a string instead.

How can I solve this?

**P.S.:** I attempted a different approach to this, using load_file_to_table, but I faced another issue. Here's the [link to the other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430169/googleapis-python-bigquery-badrequest-could-not-parse-as-date-with-message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to load data from a dataframe to BigQuery, I tried to replicate your use case on my end by referring to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-table-dataframe) using the Python client library.

The example provided by Google is working as expected. When I tried with the schema you have provided I got the same error i.e **"TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)"**

This error is occurring because for the data type you have provided in your schema and value provided in the column fields i.e

```
"date_key", "type": "DATE"
"start_time_key", "type": "TIME"
"end_time_key", "type": "TIME"
```

In these columns you have passed data type as **Date** and **Time** respectively but when passing the values you are providing it as a **Strin**g for which you are getting the TypeError i.e

```
"Date_key": "2021-01-01", "start_time_key": "19:00:00" , "end_time_key" : "21:00:00"
```

You can refer to the below code snippet and the data frame. I have replicated on my end and it is working.

**loaddata.py:**

```
import datetime

from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas
import pytz

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
table_id = "myproject.dataset1.tab4"

records = [
   {
      "clinic_key": u"cli101",
      "schedule_template_time_interval_key":"1",
      "schedule_template_key":"1",
      "date_key":datetime.date(2021,10,5),
      "schedule_owner_key":"1",
      "schedule_template_schedule_track_key":"1",
      "schedule_content_label_key":"1",
      "start_time_key":datetime.time(19,5,00),
      "end_time_key":datetime.time(20,00,00),
      "priority":1,

   },

{
      "clinic_key": u"cli102",
      "schedule_template_time_interval_key":"2",
      "schedule_template_key":"2",
      "date_key":datetime.date(2021,10,6),
      "schedule_owner_key":"2",
      "schedule_template_schedule_track_key":"2",
      "schedule_content_label_key":"2",
      "start_time_key":datetime.time(16,10,00),
      "end_time_key":datetime.time(16,50,00),
      "priority":2,

   },
   {
      "clinic_key": u"cli103",
      "schedule_template_time_interval_key":"3",
      "schedule_template_key":"3",
      "date_key":datetime.date(2021,10,7),
      "schedule_owner_key":"3",
      "schedule_template_schedule_track_key":"3",
      "schedule_content_label_key":"3",
      "start_time_key":datetime.time(19,10,00),
      "end_time_key":datetime.time(20,00,00),
      "priority":1,

   },
   {
      "clinic_key": u"cli104",
      "schedule_template_time_interval_key":"4",
      "schedule_template_key":"4",
      "date_key":datetime.date(2021,10,8),
      "schedule_owner_key":"4",
      "schedule_template_schedule_track_key":"4",
      "schedule_content_label_key":"4",
      "start_time_key":datetime.time(20,40,00),
      "end_time_key":datetime.time(21,15,00),
      "priority":3,

   },
]
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(
   records,
   # In the loaded table, the column order reflects the order of the
   # columns in the DataFrame.
   columns=[
"clinic_key",                            
"schedule_template_time_interval_key",  
"schedule_template_key",                  
"date_key",                             
"schedule_owner_key",                     
"schedule_template_schedule_track_key", 
"schedule_content_label_key",             
"start_time_key",                        
"end_time_key",                          
"priority",                               
   ],
   # Optionally, set a named index, which can also be written to the
   # BigQuery table.
  
)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
   # Specify a (partial) schema. All columns are always written to the
   # table. The schema is used to assist in data type definitions.
   schema=[
       # Specify the type of columns whose type cannot be auto-detected. For
       # example the "title" column uses pandas dtype "object", so its
       # data type is ambiguous.
       bigquery.SchemaField("clinic_key", "STRING"),
       bigquery.SchemaField("schedule_template_time_interval_key","STRING"),
       bigquery.SchemaField("schedule_template_key","STRING"),
       bigquery.SchemaField("schedule_owner_key","STRING"),
       bigquery.SchemaField("schedule_template_schedule_track_key","STRING"),
       bigquery.SchemaField("schedule_content_label_key","STRING"),
       bigquery.SchemaField("priority","INTEGER"),   
      
   ],
      write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
)

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
   dataframe, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.
job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.

table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print(
   "Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(
       table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id
   )
)
```

**Sample dataframe:**

```
      "clinic_key": u"cli101",
      "schedule_template_time_interval_key":"1",
      "schedule_template_key":"1",
      "date_key":datetime.date(2021,10,5),
      "schedule_owner_key":"1",
      "schedule_template_schedule_track_key":"1",
      "schedule_content_label_key":"1",
      "start_time_key":datetime.time(19,5,00),
      "end_time_key":datetime.time(20,00,00),
      "priority":1,
```

When you are using DATE and TIME in schema the values in the column field should be passed in **datetime.date(2021,2,21)** and **datetime.time(16,00,00)** format respectively.

**Schema Output :**

[image]

**Query Output :**

[image]

Comment: So the trick is to **use native python types instead of formatting the value to a STRING**? That's kinda unexpected, but makes sense! Thanks a lot for your in-depth analysis, Sandeep!

Comment: For those looking to do the above programmatically, I would attempt to convert the fields using the following: `df["date_key"].apply(lambda v: datetime.datetime.strptime(v, "%Y-%m-%d").date())` and `df["time_key"].apply(lambda v: datetime.datetime.strptime(v, "%H:%M:%S").time())`